# redshift sql remove all words in a given list from sentence strings

Tags: sql, string, replace, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table with chat messages, such that each row contains: `timestamp`, `user_id`, `msg_body`.

I also have a list of 'bad' words `bad_words` containing 200+ words.

Each `msg_body` has chat messages comprised of a bunch of words, some of which can be bad. I would like to remove from each `msg_body` all occurrences of words in `bad_words` and replace with empty strings and save in a new columns `new_body`.

Here is some nonworking pseudocode portraying what I  want to do:

```
select timestamp, user_id, mgs_body, 
   case when (body SIMILAR TO (select distinct words from bad_words) 
        then (do something like replace(body,badword,'')) end as new_body 
from chat_messages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [`regexp_replace`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html)

Construct a pattern that would match all of the bad words like this `'\b(very
bad|word|not-good)\b'` using [`list_agg`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html)

```
WITH re AS (SELECT '\b(' || LISTAGG(DISTINCT words, '|') || ')\b' pattern FROM bad_words)
SELECT
    timestamp
  , user_id
  , body
  , REGEXP_REPLACE(body, re.pattern, '') new_body
FROM chat_messages, re
```

Comment: This is a great way to do it, though apparently LISTAGG limits the number of words you can concatenate.